# How to process gdoc spreadsheet in the Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, gdata-api

I have a app on the GAE. And need save entries of spreadsheet which is located in the Google docs to database. I assume that `StringIO`, `xlrd`, `gdata-api` can help to implement it. But it seems that the method `gd_client.Export` of gdata-api is not provided file parameter. Only provide `file_path` argument. Unfortunately the App can't create a file on the GAE.

Do you know that how to save the spreadsheet to GAE's database?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Save a copy of it, or 'process' it?

Comment: yeah, trying  to save the rows of spreadsheet to GAE's model

Comment: You want to store the cells in a way that's accessible from your App Engine app? Why are you trying to download the data as an excel document, then? The GData API lets you access cells of the spreadsheet directly.